# How to increase density of 3d points in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a gray image of the surface, and I build a 3d plot using arrays `x, y, z` as points. I get them like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(namefile, 0)
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1]]

x = xx.ravel()
y = yy.ravel()
z = img.ravel()
```

I need these arrays, since I use them as particles, but I need the distance between the particles to be less than the specified `dx`. Is there a way to do this using Python?

### Example:

Let's say I multiply `x, y, z` by `dx` and now i have points (x, y, z) and (x+dx, y, z1). Problem is that abs(z-z1) not necessary less than dx.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I guess that multiplying `x`, `y`, `z` by say `0.1`, is not what you are looking for. Can you please edit you post, and add a numerical example?

Comment: Still not clear enough... is `z` a gray level? Are you looking for the maximum gap between two gray levels (and dividing `z` by that value [and multiply by `dx`])? What is the range of `z`? is it `[0, 255]`? Start with a binary example: `z` has only two values: `0` and `255`. Do we need to divide `z` by `dx/255 `?

Answer (score 0):

Just resize (increase) your gray image, and you'll increase number of points with (bilinear or bicubic) interpolation. If you'll  increase each dimension 10 times, then divide your grid step 10 times. You'll get more density.